# editing with AJAX and PHP\mysql

Tags: php, jquery

with plenty of visits i found helpful answers from all of you and hope this also give me some idea about my problem.

Basically i'm trying to edit mysql data with ajax. i have done with following code.

**Step 1-   i loaded data from server with following script**

```
$("#editselected,#addselected").live("click", function(){
   var whatto=$(this).attr('id');var edit_ids = new Array();
   $(".selectable:checked").each(function() {
   edit_ids.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
   $("#editadd").load("ajaxloads/addedit.php?idarray="+edit_ids+"&action="+whatto,Hide_Load());
   //centerPopup();//loadPopup();
     });
```

**AND ITs Server DATA is**

```
if($selectall_action=='editselected'){   ?>
    <table id="main" class="editallmainwidth">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col" >Vendor</th>
    <th scope="col" >ItemType</th>
    <th scope="col" >ItemCode</th>
    <th scope="col" >ItemName</th>
    <th scope="col" >SerialNo</th>
    <th scope="col" >AssetCode</th>
    <th scope="col" >Ownership</th>
    <th scope="col" >PO</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
   $ids= split(",",$selectall_id_array);
foreach($ids as $sid)
{

$stock=mysql_query("select * FROM $region where id='$sid'");

            while($q=mysql_fetch_array($stock))
            {
    echo "<tr>";      

    echo "<td width=\"5%\"><input type='hidden' name='id_all' value='{$q[8]}' /><input type='text'  name='vend_all' value='$q[0]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"5%\"><input type='text' name='type_all' value='$q[1]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"8%\"><input type='text' name='code_all' value='$q[2]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"20%\"><input type='text' name='desc_all' value='$q[3]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"10%\"><input type='text' name='seno_all' value='$q[4]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"5%\"><input type='text' name='acode_all' value='$q[5]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"2%\"><input type='text' name='os_all' value='$q[9]' /></td>";
    echo "<td width=\"5%\"><input type='text' name='porder_all' value='$q[12]' />  </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
            }

     }  
     ?>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <fieldset id="add">
            <input type="submit" id='editall' name="Modify" value="EditAll" />   </fieldset>
```

**Step-2 Then I edited The loaded text boxes filled with server data and send back ajax request to server**

```
$("#editall").live("click", function(){

    var id_alledit = new Array();
    var vendor_alledit = new Array();
    var type_alledit = new Array();
    var code_alledit = new Array();
    var desc_alledit = new Array();
    var seno_alledit = new Array();
    var acode_alledit = new Array();
    var os_alledit = new Array();
    var po_alledit = new Array();

    var isedited=$("#editall").val();



$("input[name='id_all']").map(function(index) {
id_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

var tcount=$("input[name='id_all']").length;

 $("input[name='vend_all']").map(function(index) {
vendor_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
 });


 $("input[name='type_all']").map(function(index) {
 type_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
 });

 $("input[name='code_all']").map(function(index) {
code_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

 $("input[name='desc_all']").map(function(index) {
 desc_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
 });

 $("input[name='seno_all']").map(function(index) {
 seno_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

$("input[name='acode_all']").map(function(index) {
acode_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
$("input[name='os_all']").map(function(index) {
os_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
 $("input[name='porder_all']").map(function(index) {
po_alledit.push($(this).attr('value'));
});



jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",url:"ajaxloads/addedit.php",
data:"&id_arrays=" + id_alledit + "&vend_arrays=" + vendor_alledit + "&type_arrays=" +         type_alledit + "&code_arrays=" + code_alledit + "&desc_arrays=" + desc_alledit +   "&seno_arrays=" + seno_alledit + "&os_arrays=" + os_alledit + "&acode_arrays=" +   acode_alledit + "&po_arrays=" + po_alledit + "&ifedited=" + isedited + "&tcount=" + tcount  ,
      complete:function(data){


 //$("#main").load("ajaxloads/addedit.php",null,function(responseText){ 
 //$("#main").html(responseText);
//$('tr:even',this).addClass("odd");
   alert(data.responseText);
 //}); 

   }
 }); 

  //disablePopup(); 
   return false;
  });
```

**AND Updation was done with the following server side code**

```
if(isset($_POST[ifedited])=='EditAll')

{

$id_count= $_POST[tcount];
$idarray=split(",",$_POST[id_arrays]);
$vendarray=split(",",$_POST[vend_arrays]);
$typearray=split(",",$_POST[type_arrays]);
$codearray=split(",",$_POST[code_arrays]);
$descarray=split(",",$_POST[desc_arrays]);
$senoarray=split(",",$_POST[seno_arrays]);
$acodearray=split(",",$_POST[acode_arrays]);
$osarray=split(",",$_POST[os_arrays]);
$poarray=split(",",$_POST[po_arrays]);
//print_r($idarray);

       for($i=0;$i<=$id_count;$i++)
 {
 //echo $id_count;
 echo $idarray[$i];
 echo $typearray[$i];
 echo $vendarray[$i];
 echo $codearray[$i];
 echo $descarray[$i];
 echo $senoarray[$i];
 echo $acodearray[$i];
 echo $osarray[$i];
 echo $poarray[$i];

 mysql_query("update Query");



 }

    }
```

*Every thing working fine but it seems like steps for this are being used are 
quite lengthy and may cause a performance issue.
i Need if some can suggest me a better way of doing all this. Or if **JSON** is better option? and if it is then how i can Creat A JSON with associative arrays.

Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reccomend you use JSON to do it. If you have a JSON returned like this

```
{
  "foo": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
  "bar": "ABCDEFG",
  "baz": [52, 97]
}
```

Use jQuery to grab it like this

```
$.getJSON('ajax-mysql/json.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html('<p>' + data.foo + '</p>'
    + '<p>' + data.baz[1] + '</p>');
});
```

**Update:** Sending the data back to mysql. Javascript

```
var data = new Array();
data[0] = $("input1").val();
data[1] = $("input2").val();
data[2] = $("input3").val();
```

etc...

```
var mysql_field=new Array();
mysql_field[0] = 'field1';
mysql_field[1] = 'field2';
mysql_field[2] = 'field3';

var jq = new Array();
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){jq[i] = mysql_field[i]+'=\''+data[i]+'\'';}
jq=jq.join('&');
```

you can replace `data` and `mysql_field` with the current variables you have. Now here's how you would update it with jQuery..

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
  $.post("/ajax-update.php",'"'+jq+'"',function (output){
    $("somediv").html(output); // the output on /ajax-update.php after data is submitted
  });
});
```

and on the `ajax-update.php` file you could use something like

```
$field[0] = $_POST['field1'];
$field[1] = $_POST['field2'];
$field[2] = $_POST['field2'];
$db->query_update("table",$field,"id=1"); //update where id=1
```

That query is how you would do it, using this great mysql wrapper class at http://www.ricocheting.com/code/php/mysql-database-class-wrapper. Check it out it'll make your life really easy. All you do is put this at the top of your php file

```
require("Database.class.php");
$db = new Database("server_name", "mysql_user", "mysql_pass", "mysql_database");
```

Comment: Thanks for your urgent response, it seems like you are suggesting encoding in json through php and then creat html ?  but how i will send back to server the edited arrays of data back to php? can please give simple example

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was basically saying. Can you clarify more on what you want to send back to the mysql server.. Also, checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php :)

Comment: send back to mysql means, as you know in my example i first loaded the page with ajax and data was stored in array of textbox in NAme And Value.  From your idea of JSON what i understood that i will use $.getjson instead of Load. but after loading json in html element how i will iterate through each HTML element to creat same type of JSON and decode in PHP. In simple how i will creat a JSON of Edited value with its field name to use in update query. infact having no idea.

Comment: So, are you going to update with `ajax`, after the values are edited. Or are you going to do it *without* ajax on the same page? If you're going to update the edited values with ajax, its fairly easy with JSON, if not.. then you don't even need JSON to do it.

Comment: ya sure i will use ajax. please can give me a little example to edit with JSON.

Comment: a few more questions. (1) are the updated values in input fields? (2) do the inputs have ids or classes? (3) does the update happen after the submit button is clicked?

Comment: 1- values are in input fields, 2- classes and Ids are used but only grab the reference of dynamically created input boxes 3- ya update is trigered after submit button clicked but not using any form

Comment: Thanks for your time, i'll try it and will let you know. But it seems little confusing because my text boxes will dynamically populated and then dynamically send back. i think i need to loop to send them back for update

Answer (score 0):

for this question : "how i can Creat A JSON with associative arrays.". Try using the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) function.

You could also :

- stop using the [deprecated] split function that uses regex and use the explode function.
- use quotes on your array's call like here :  `$_POST[tcount]`  :    `$_POST['tcount']`
- while isset returns boolean, this test is quite weird : `if(isset($_POST[ifedited])=='EditAll'){`
- stop using `SELECT * FROM ...` but write `SELECT field1, field2 FROM ....`
- add a third parameter to this call : `mysql_fetch_array($stock, MYSQL_NUM)`
- here :

  foreach($ids as $sid)
  {

  $stock=mysql_query("select * FROM $region where id='$sid'");

try using the IN operator of the WHERE clause to avoid multi-queries.

Your code is very difficult to read because not well parsed but still, there are lots of improvements that should affect performances ...

Comment: thanks for your helpful improvements.                                 But here my concentration have been graped by JSON that seems little simple. i wish if someone can give me little idea how to convert my existing code in JSON